# Phonegap failed to install sample app onto android emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I've been trying to install a helloworld app onto android 4.3 emulator with the command "phonegap run android". It was built successfully. I believe the error occurred during the installation. I've been trying to fix it for hours with no luck. Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using Mac. The OS version is 10.7.5.

Below is the error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 15 seconds
WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to myavd
Waiting for emulator...
shell.js: internal error
Error: spawn EMFILE
    at errnoException (child_process.js:977:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:924:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:712:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:604:15)
    at Object.exports.exec (child_process.js:575:18)
    at execSync (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1793:9)
    at Object._exec (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1130:12)
    at Object.exec (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1487:23)
    at Object.module.exports.sleep (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:255:15)
    at Object.module.exports.wait_for_emulator (/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:221:14)
```

Comment: just a suggestion, try compile with phonegap and then install it on emulator with adb

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that before and it worked. But I was still trying to figure out why installing from the command line failed.

Comment: Try using a `-V` flag to specify verbose output. Might want to break it down into `build` and `install` as well due to the verbose.

Comment: Any news on this? I am having the same problem...

Comment: Looks like Android SDK and ADB wasn't correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

EMFILE is error when you try to open more file descriptors than your system supports. [File descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is an indicator for accessing a file. Generally the limit is 256 on OSX. The easiest solution is to increase the limit by doing `ulimit -n 10480`. But this solution would only be for your current session of terminal. The permanent approach would to put this into your shell profile `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, but it is not the recommended approach as it might cause some system issues.

You can search more on [this issue](https://www.google.no/search?q=Fatal%20error%3a%20spawn%20EMFILE) on google